# How to extract different substrings between certain substrings from array list?

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I'm not sure how to properly ask this question, but hopefully this example will clear things up.

I have a list of Strings, for example ("AS3K**4455**NJNSADN**4455**KLMDSMF043J**4455**NKFDG**4455**KMMFDG")

As you can see, there is "4455" repeating. I'll have a long list of stings and let's say 4455 will represent start/end of message I want to extract. I'm not what is the best way to achieve this, so if anyone ever encoutered similar problem, please halp :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need the actual '4455' part, you can just split on the string.

```
String[] parts = myString.split("4455");
```

Giving you an array of strings. You can also pass a regular expression here.

If you do need that prefix/suffix you could just add it back.

Answer (score 5):

You can split them by using a `StringTokenizer`, and setting your delim as you prefer (in your example, it's 4455), ie:

```
String string = "AS3K4455NJNSADN4455KLMDSMF043J4455NKFDG4455KMMFDG";
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(string, "4455");
while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
    System.out.println("Token: "+ tokenizer.nextToken()); //or do whatever you need with your token, here I'm printing
}
```

Output:

```
Token: AS3K
Token: NJNSADN
Token: KLMDSMF0
Token: 3J
Token: NKFDG
Token: KMMFDG
```